# iPhone iOS 5.0 OpenGl ES 2.0

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5, opengl-es-2.0

Seriously i've been looking for weeks, even months for some serious help with OpenGl on the iPhone with XCode 4.2, I need a good tutorial on how to begin with the 'OpenGL Game' template with the new XCode 4.2 and then progress from there to actually understand how to make my game come to life. I have a lot of experience with Windows and XNA with shaders and all the maths involved and i already have an app on the App Store that doesn't use OpenGL but i just can't get started with it, please help, thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These video tutorials are quite old, but are clear and helpful and I found them fantastic.

I am currently using the framework designed over the course to implement a game.

[http://www.71squared.com/iphone-tutorials/](https://www.youtube.com/user/71squared)

EDIT: Link directed to youtube channel, website no longer exists

Comment: link is dead still

Comment: @MysteryPancake i suspect its been broken again, since that was 3 years ago

Answer (score 4):

There is a very good book about the subject: 'OpenGL ES 2.0 Programming Guide'

You can find more info here: http://opengles-book.com/

Answer (score 1):

They has good tutorials 
http://www.raywenderlich.com
and
http://games.ianterrell.com